# Matplotlib doesn't rotate 3D plots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have written the following test code to demonstrate the problem:

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x=np.linspace(0,1,10)
y=np.linspace(0,1,10)

X,Y=np.meshgrid(x,y)

ax = plt.gca(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X,Y,X+Y)
plt.show()
```

This code plots a 3d surface but I cannot grab and rotate it. Where is the problem?

Comment: It works fine for me. Perhaps you have issues with your plotting engine. Try issue a %pylab qt at the command prompt before running the code

Comment: Thank you very much! That was exactly the problem. For later reference, I was using canopy so I just changed the graphic handler of python through its preferences!

Comment: You are welcome. You should also experiment with switching interactive mode on, import matplotlib.pyplot as plt followed by plt.ion(). This allows you to keep your shell when plotting figures. I have seen quite some issues with different engines, especially on Windows.

Comment: @naji Please post your solution as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I have had this same problem, adding the following lines *before* importing anything matplotlib related (i.e. above line 2 in your example) fixes the issue.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt4Agg')
```

So, your example would be:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt4Agg')

from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x=np.linspace(0,1,10)
y=np.linspace(0,1,10)

X,Y=np.meshgrid(x,y)

ax = plt.gca(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X,Y,X+Y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: However, this doesn't seem to fix the issue for me when embedded in a WxPython GUI. IF anyone has a better solution, that would be greatly appreciated.